# Const speechText is undefined

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit

My javascript handler uses a call to an API, and returns a text string (body) which gets assigned to the const `speechText`. But as you can see in the log results initially speechText throws an error because it's not defined, but when the `request.get` method gets called it appears to have returned the proper result.

Is this an asynchronous issue, and if so, how do I restructure the code to give the result (body) when I need it? I think the code is executing the `return handlerInput.responseBuilder` before the result comes back from the API call.

Here's my code:

```
const NumberIntentHandler = {

    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
          && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'NumberIntent';
    },

     handle(handlerInput) {
        console.log('At NumberIntentHandler');

        let slotNum = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.number.value;

        const url = `http://numbersapi.com/${slotNum}`;
        console.log('url: ', url);

        request.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
            console.log('error: ', error); // Print the error if one occurred
            console.log('statusCode: ', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
            console.log('body: ', body); // Print the body 

            const speechText = body;
            console.log('speechText: ', speechText); // Print the speechText     
        });

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
          .speak(speechText)
          .withSimpleCard('Here is your fact: ', speechText) 
          .getResponse();
     }
};
```

[image: Log results]

Comment: Sorry, I posted then had to edit it.

Comment: Your `speechText` variable isn't defined outside of the scope of the get request.  Furthermore, even if it were in the correct scope, your current return statement will run before the async function returns. You want to include the return statement inside the function passed into your async get request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request` is an asynchronous event. So, while the request is happening, your `return` statement is evaluated and therefore `speechText` hasn't been set yet.

In addition, your defining the `speechText` inside of a function which means it wont be in scope for the `return` either